# XCode - Failed to register bundle identifier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, provisioning-profile, bundle-identifier

I started using a new Macbook Pro, and I opened an XCode project I had on OneDrive. When I try to run it, I get the error below

> Signing for "Project5" requires a development team. Select a
> development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.

I checked which were the settings under "Signing and Capabilities" and I noticed it was missing the "Team". So I created one with my Apple ID. I try to run it again and I get two errors this time

> Failed to register bundle identifier: The app identifier
> "com.example.Project5" cannot be registered to your development team
> because it is not available. Change your bundle identifier to a unique
> string to try again.
>
> No profiles for 'com.example.Project5' were found: Xcode couldn't find
> any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching
> 'com.example.Project5'.

At this point I am not 100% to understand which is the problem. I tried also to run it ticking off the "Automatically manage signing", but it asks me for a "Provisioning profile". I searched on Google but the solutions I found did not help me to solve this problem. Any idea on how to fix this? I am missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: This is due to the fact that only bundle identifiers must be unique, clearly someone has used `com.example.Project5` before. So changing it to something unique, as the marked answer alludes to but doesn't quite say, is the correct solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change "com.example.Project5" to "com.YourDevName.YourNameProject"

Comment: That's not the correct solution. I don't want to change package names forever.

Comment: The bundle ID is unique. If someone has already taken the ID, you need to change it.

Comment: Ok, but sometimes this error occurs when bundle ID is not taken, but become outdated after some period of time like a month. Then I need to change it, regenerate certificates and I can change it back again to the previous value after some time. Apple could organize it better. Especially for development (not deployment) purposes.

Comment: Can you provide more information on how to regenerate the profile?

Comment: Regenerate which profile? You mean how to declare a bundle id?